# Returning a json array using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, concrete5

Here's the javascript:

```
var data = $('form#registration-form').serialize();
$.post(
'<?php echo $this->url('/register', 'do_register')?>',
function(data) {
 alert(data);
},
'json'
);
```

And here's the ending of the do_register() method:

```
if( $_REQUEST['format']=='JSON' ){
$jsonHelper=Loader::helper('json'); 
echo $jsonHelper->encode($registerData);
die;
}
```

The `$registerData` variable holds all the data I need. I want the function to return it after the ajax call. However, when I specify dataType: 'json' nothing is returned. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you call the php directly what does it output? Can you provide details on Loader and what it returns.

Comment: Any erros in console? Why the third parameter is `dataType: 'json'`, it should be just `"json"`

Comment: If I don't use ajax, it returns a separate page with the HTML form and all output data. This piece of code returns a JSON array with all the output data that I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in url

```
$.post(
'<?php echo $this->url("/register", "do_register"); ?>?format=JSON',
function(data) {
 alert(data);
},
'json'
);
```

Also you can use following line in php part to get json values

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Comment: try this in url '<?php echo $this->url("/register", "do_register")?>?format=JSON'

Answer (score 0):

I suppose problem is somewhere here:

`'<?php echo $this->url('/register', 'do_register')?>',` in using quotes.

Use double and single quotes:

`"<?php echo $this->url('/register', 'do_register')?>",`.

Comment: It doesn't help. The response tab in Chrome shows an entire page being returned.

Comment: json will be returned if `$_REQUEST['format'] == 'JSON'` is true. Does your url satisfy this condition?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to receive right suggestion with little description.

Y'd better to paste more php & javascript code, with much more context, thing to be simple.

And another suggestion, mixed coding is bad. separating the javascript and php with php template such as Smarty.

```
var data = $('form#registration-form').serialize();
$.post(
'<?php echo $this->url('/register', 'do_register')?>',
function(data) {
 alert(data);
},
'json'
);
```

this source file of above code is a php file ?

Debug with firebug to capture weather the ajax request sent or not

Answer (score -1):

Why use JSON helper??

```
json_decode(string $json);
json_encode(mixed $value); //normally array...
```

it is built-in in php.